# Forge Viewer photorealistic rendering with Vray

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, 3dsmax

Here's a demo of three.js connected to Vray (just to illustrate how it can look/work in a render farm environment from 3ds Max):
https://youtu.be/x673Ubn8c5U

We've been testing varies ways to translate our Vray materials to the Viewer but the Vray materials isn't read/translated. We've been testing with both .max and .skp wothout any luck.

Does anybody know whether there's any workflow for Vray to SVF?

Comment: Can you send the model through to forge.help@autodesk.com if possible via a file sharing service (e.g. weTransfer/GDrive/Dropbox etc) with a brief description (ideally w screenshots) so we can look into this and potentially escalate to our engineering team for further check up?